# Routing keeps returning 404 instead of displaying other views besides index, users, and error in Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am setting up a site on Express.JS with express-generator but ran into a hiccup with the routing. Currently I keep receiving the "error" view and a 404 message whenever sending a GET request to another route I set up ("/hook"). Currently the two routes that are working is "/" which goes to the "index" and "/users" which goes responds a message. I would like to see why I am getting this error as the others work.

Here is the app.js file:

```js
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
var hookRouter = require("./routes/hook");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/hook", hookRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// // error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  //   // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the index router

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the hook router:

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET hook page. */
router.get("/hook", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hook Page Works");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please let me know there is any more info I can give. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The hook router needs to be:

```
/* GET hook page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hook Page Works");
});
```

This:

```
app.use("/hook", hookRouter);
```

has already used the `/hook` part of the path so within the router, you just want `/`.

---

Your original combination of:

```
app.use("/hook", hookRouter);

router.get("/hook", ...);
```

will respond to the URL `/hook/hook`.